# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, addressbook, peoplepicker

In a Project having already ObjC, I'm adding a Swift Class

```
import AddressBookUI
class MyVC : UITableViewController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {
}
```

MyApp-Swift.h:289:42: Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UINavigationControllerDelegate'?

No, Swift, I really mean `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate`. Really wondering what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: You think I didn't? I've worked with the AB Framework since 2008..... Something is just a bit different in Swift — and it probably have nothing to do with AB but generally me not understand something with Swift/ObjC.

Comment: just import a swift file name it MyVC and just use your above code and don't put your above code in header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the reason this works with `ABRecord` in pure Swift, but not in the Objective-C compatibility header is that there is a `typealias` which the latter apparently doesn't translate back correctly:

`typealias ABRecordRef = ABRecord`

see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ABRecordRef

Might be worth filing a Radar

Answer (score 1):

I need to add

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

in my `Briding-Header.h`. One could think the `import` in my Swift file was enough. It was not.

That said, now I have a new problem when implementing

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
}
```

Here comes the next error:

*-Swift.h:297:110: Expected a type*

It has a problem with the `ABRecord` type in

```
didSelectPerson:(ABRecord)
```

Doesn't help if I also import `AddressBook` in Briding Header or Swift File.

Comment: whay are u adding all this stuf in your header file

Answer (score 1):

You can check the code I've used [here](https://github.com/dfreniche/StackOverflowQA/tree/master/29253262)

## Pure Swift project, no Objective-C involved

For me, this is compiling fine **without using any Bridging-Header**

```swift
import UIKit
import AddressBook
import AddressBookUI

class ViewController: UITableViewController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {


    }
}
```

I'm adding relevant frameworks (AddressBook, AddressBookUI) to the *link binary with libraries* phase of my target

[image: adding relevant frameworks]

## Objective-C Project, with Bridging Header

My Bridging-Header.h:

```objectivec
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

- make sure your Bridging-Header is properly referenced in your target

[image: Bridging-Header]

- swift VC code is the same as above

Comment: Do you have ObjC in your project or is this straight Swift?

Comment: This is just a pure Swift sample project I created to test your problem. Are you having this problem with a Objective-C project?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my **second** Problem thanks to [@neonacho on Twitter](http://twitter.com/NeoNacho/status/580710137284947968). Instead of `ABRecord` I had to use `ABRecordRef` to compile. Not sure why Diego's code works and not mine. So it became

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, 
                                      didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
}
```

and it works.